# How do I ensure that scroll bars come up on this styled text-area?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a .net textbox (text area) inside a div like this:

```
 <div class="description-textarea">

                <asp:TextBox ID="tbDescription" runat="server" CssClass="radial" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="39" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>

                <span id="spnCharsLeft" runat="server" class="">1000 characters left</span>

            </div>
```

And I have the CSS...

```
#content-main #upload .image-and-description .right .description-textarea{ padding-top:6px; width:370px;}
#content-main #upload .image-and-description .right .description-textarea textarea { overflow: hidden; display: block; min-height: 85px; width:423px;}
#content-main #upload .image-and-description .right .description-textarea span{ line-height:40px;}
```

When I type in lots of text I dont get any scroll bars come up so I cant see what im typing. Is these any way to make the text area show the scroll bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `overflow: hidden;` does hide the scroll bars as Tsar said.  However, just getting rid of it may not be enough to make the scroll bars appear. The default value of `overflow: visible;` will just let the extra content render outside the element.

You can force the issue with `overflow: scroll;` or have automatic scroll bars when they're needed with `overflow: auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

scrollbars are being hidden by this css property:
`overflow: hidden;` get rid of it and you'll see the precious scrollbars.

Comment: hi tsar thanks for the reply and the humerous comment on my 'precious scrollbars' lol.  eaj had all the info I needed but I have +1'ed you!